# How is domain knowledge developed?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, inference, data-mining

Most sources I've read state that domain knowledge is crucial for making good inferences. As an example, if I'm conducting a study to assess the importance of a new biomarker for heart attacks, the common advice is to ask a domain expert what are strong risk factors for heart attacks so I can include them in my model to 1) improve performance and 2) control for confounding and assess how much new information the new biomarker adds.

These recommendations make sense and I generally agree that given domain knowledge we should choose subject matter expertise over information from data mining, but this makes me wonder, how was this domain knowledge developed in the first place?

For example, pretend I have just discovered a new disease. I'd like to start studying risk factors for this disease, but because the disease is so new there are no previously known risk factors. The doctors can only guess which risk factors are important, but there is no real prior knowledge or data to support their guesses. What would be the appropriate way to start developing a body of domain knowledge about potential risk factors?

The ideas that come to mind are to consider the basic biology behind the disease but this may be 1) non-existent and 2) basic biology doesn't always translate easily to clinical risk factors. Another approach would be data mining, but I'm not sure what approaches would be appropriate or trustworthy. Would it be better to start with purely descriptive studies and then after several descriptive studies are published then start trying to make inferences.

I ask this question because some domain experts I've talked with seem to prefer a data mining approach to identify prognostic factors and then use the results to influence their domain knowledge. They feel that their science should adapt to fit the data. Just like statisticians placing the burden on the domain experts, this feels like domain experts placing the burden on the statisticians to solve the same problem, almost like no one wants to take responsibility. With these experiences in mind, this makes me curious about how domain knowledge is developed in the real world and how statisticians and domain experts can optimally work together to develop new knowledge.

Comment: Are you asking "how to obtain domain knowledge if there isn't any"? Then you seem to be answering yourself.